# How to export pdf to images with the right size?

Tags: pdf

For some reasons I need to convert pdf documents to images frequently, but the image sizes of them aren't equal, and I have to resize these images subsequently. Is there a way that I can convert these pdf files to a image size I specified? I'm a Windows user, so I need Windows applications, thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is it that you’re trying to achieve? Put a rendered image of the PDF in a page’s center? Or scaled to fit? Do all PDFs have the “paper size”?

Comment: I need to generate thumbnails from PDFs. I've found one online pdf converter lets me to do this, on it I can set the image dimensions and background colour, it's really useful to me, here's the address: http://pdftojpg.me/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need to do. For Windows I have this software [Dysprosium (Edition 2015)](http://messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html). One feature it has got is to convert PDF's to image files (png, gif, tiff, bmp,  but jpg not sure) depending to the users' choice. You can decide on scale before-hand. You are able to convert images back to PDF files, too. It is free and works on Solaris, MAC, Linux. You need free Java already in your computer to run it. It does not need installation. Put it in the bin if you do not need it anymore. Use PDF to Image button. Software is versatile and has other features that you might use; for example, change default size and zoom of all your PDF files.

[image]

There is a [help page here](http://messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Howto51.html) to utilize the software.